# Windows 10 блокирует запуск программы

Tags: .net, windows-10

Windows 10 с последними обновлениями блокирует запуск софта, уведомление с текстом ошибки:

Название окна: "Warning!"

Текст в окне: "Spyware tool is executed on this PC. Please close the application App.exe try again"

Defender отключен, SmartScreen отключен. Сторонних антивирусов нет.

Что блокирует запуск?

Comment: может быть не стоит запускать это приложение? Для начала я бы проверил само приложение сторонними антивирусами.

Comment: @KoVadim, это мое приложение, я сам его написал. Оно на дотнете. При запуске вносит настройки в реестр, меняет профиль электропитания и т.д. Приложение запускается от админа. Проблема именно на десятке возникает.

Comment: так как оно вносит изменения в реестр, они могут быть очень опасными. По хорошему, такое приложение нужно подписывать.

Comment: @KoVadim, оно подписано, правда мною же созданным сертификатом. Но сути это не меняет. Я сам запускаю свое приложение на своем ПК.

Comment: своим сертификатом. Если сертификат правильно не добавить в систему, то толку с этого мало. В любом случае осталось последнее - нужно просто в антивирусную компанию отправить  Ваш бинарь с жалобой на false positive.

Comment: @KoVadim, с какого это? В какую антивирусную компанию? Объясните пожалуйста поподробнее, что именно блокирует запуск.

Comment: в данном случае - в майкрософт. Но приложение скорее всего блокирует дефендер. Ну не умеет майкрософт "выключать" полностью такую функциональность.

Comment: @KoVadim, теперь все ясно. Это случайно не из-за этого был скандал каспера с ms?

Comment: возможно, но там не все так просто.  Но это не тема данного сайта.

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо. Все ясно.